# Need assistance regarding textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

[UITextFieldDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) says

"Asks the delegate if the specified text should be changed." regarding `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`

I have `UITextField` and only excepting numbers, I don't want 0 as the first number in `UITextField`, if user press 0 it must not appear if it is the first place.

What is the purpose of this method when its functionality can be achieved using editing changed event?

Comment: See my asnwer ..i Hope you will get your result.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;

    if(newLength>1 && range.location==0 && [string isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
        textField.text = [textField.text substringFromIndex:0];
        return NO;
    }
    else
        return (newLength == 1 && [string isEqualToString:@"0"]) ? NO : YES;

    return YES;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, Please can you tell me what is the purpose of this method when editing change event can do this much easily?

Comment: If user enter 12345 and then try to enter 0 in first place this code will not work.

Comment: When you type in UITextField delegate will pass an event to this delegate method for changed text.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this one...

```
   -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    /* for backspace */
    if([string length]==0)
    {
        return YES;
    }

    /*  limit to only numeric characters  */

    NSCharacterSet *myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];
    for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++)
    {
        if ([string isEqualToString:@"0"] && [textField.text length] == 0)
            return NO;
        else
        {
            unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
            if ([myCharSet characterIsMember:c])
                return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

I hope this answer will be helpful...